# Using <label for=""> with a HtmlHelper rendered element with an id that contains a space

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, label-for

If I have a plain checkbox `<input>` element with an `id` attribute that contains a space, I can still use `<label for="">` to bind a label to the element, and then click on the label text to toggle the checkbox value:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="remember me" />
<label for="remember me">Remember me</label>
```

However, if I create the same `<input>` element using the [HtmlHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx) class, `<label for="">` does not seem to bind the label to the label text. When I click on the label text, the checkbox does not toggle:

```
@Html.CheckBox("remember me")
<label for="remember me">Remember me</label>
```

Why is the behavior differing when I use HtmlHelper? Is it possible to use `<label for="">` with a HtmlHelper rendered element that has an `id` that contains a space?

---

Please note, the main purpose of this question is to document something interesting that I discovered. According to [HTML 5 standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), the `id` attribute should be at least one character, and should **not** contain any space characters. I came across some code that obviously didn't follow the W3C recommendations, and while cleaning it up, found a solution for the above problem, so I figured I may as well share what I found in case this can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the HtmlHelper creates the `<input>` element, it replaces all spaces in the `id` attribute with underscores.

If you inspect the rendered HTML code, you will see the the `input` element renders as follows:

```
<input id="remember_me" name="remember me" value="true" type="checkbox">
```

If you want to associate a label with the above element, therefore, you need to replace all spaces with underscores in the `for`string:

```
@Html.CheckBox("remember me")
<label for="remember_me">Remember me</label>
```

---

Another way you can possibly avoid the above problem is by skipping the `for=""` attribute all together, and just wrapping the `<label>` tag around the entire `input` element:

```
<label>
    @Html.CheckBox("remember me")
    Remember me
</label>
```

I've found this solution to sometimes causes issues, however, if I had some CSS styles set for all label elements, and didn't want the styles applied to all the elements that the label surrounded.